# A recursive template type for a container / typename forwarding

Tags: c++

Is there any way to get a recursive template type? I have a container for which I want to specify an underlying storage strategy. The inner template must however use the outer template's type, so it causes a loop in the type definition -- which isn't possible to specify.

About what I want:

```
template<typename C>
struct inner {
    C * object[16];
};

template<typename T, typename Inner>
struct container {
    T value;
    Inner<container> holder;
};
```

C++11 solutions are fine (though I'm still on gcc 4.6.3).

Comment: There is something called "curiously recursive template pattern" (CRTP)? Maybe it will help, not sure... http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern

Comment: What are the new behaviors that this recursive data type will have that differentiate it from a linked list?

Comment: @abiessu, my current use is actually for a radix tree. Each node has an index of how to get to the next node, and `inner` is what specifies the strategy for that index. That is, the template allows saying how the children are managed, as opposed to a fixed red-black, hash, or other strategy.

Comment: @Jimbo, this is not the curiously recursive pattern as `inner` is not a base-class of `container`.

Comment: @edA-qa, yes right you are, my mistake... doh

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to tell the compiler that `Inner` is a templated class:

```
template<typename T, template<typename> class Inner>
struct container {
    T value;
    Inner<container> holder;
};
```

Comment: Why does it have to be `class` before Inner? I understand it's not a generic parameter anymore, but a class type, though I expected `struct` to also work. Since it doesn't I'm not sure I quite understand.

Comment: @edA-qamort-ora-y It's how templates work. You can either use the generic `typename` keyword, or `class`. However in this case since `Inner` is a template class itself, it has to be declared as a template `class`. You can define templated structs, but not inside a template argument list.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you're adding the `Inner` type template parameter, since you're defining `holder` to be a type based on `Container` and `inner`, both of which are available at the point you're declaring holder.

Are you planning on using any type other than `struct inner` as a template param to `Container`? If not, the following simplified code compiled and ran for me in VS2010 :

```
#include <vector>
#include <stdio.h>

template <typename C>
struct inner{
    C * objects[16];
    bool hasobj;

    inner():hasobj(false){}
};

template <typename T>
class Container {
    inner<Container> holder;
    T value;
public:

    Container(const T& valueP){
        value = valueP;
    }
    void AddChild(Container* rhs){
        holder.objects[0] = rhs; //Always using first location, just for example
        holder.hasobj = true;
    }

    void PrintStuff()const{
        if(holder.hasobj){
            holder.objects[0]->PrintStuff();
        }
        printf("VAL IS %d\n", value);
    }
};

int main(){
    Container<int> c(10);

    Container<int> c1(20);
    c1.AddChild(&c);
    c1.PrintStuff();
}
```

Basically, this is assuming that the `container` is always defining `holder` in terms of `inner`, which helps get rid of the extra template parameter, when defining `Container`. Hope this helps :)
arun

Comment: About Inner, yes, that is the purpose, you can select the type being used for the inner class.